# Android multi touch - IllegalArgumentException in TouchMove event

Tags: java, android, input, multi-touch, touchscreen

I'm trying to get a list of pointers, whether they are down, and their positions in pixels on the screen, so I can port my desktop game to android. To do so, I have wrote this onTouch handler.

```
private boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
    final int action = e.getActionMasked();

    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            surfaceView.queueEvent(() -> postTouchEvent(FINGER_0, true, e.getX(), e.getY()));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            surfaceView.queueEvent(() -> postTouchEvent(FINGER_0, false, e.getX(), e.getY()));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        {
            final int index = e.getActionIndex();
            final int finger = index + 1;

            if (finger < FINGER_1 || finger > FINGER_9)
                break;

            final boolean isDown = action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN;
            surfaceView.queueEvent(() -> postTouchEvent(finger, isDown, e.getX(), e.getY()));
        }
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            for (int i = 0; i < e.getPointerCount(); i++)
            {
                final int finger = i + 1;

                if (finger < FINGER_0 || finger > FINGER_9)
                    break;

                surfaceView.queueEvent(() ->
                        postTouchEvent(finger, true, e.getX(finger - 1), e.getY(finger - 1)));
            }
            for (int i = e.getPointerCount(); i < FINGER_9; i++)
            {
                final int finger = i + 1;
                surfaceView.queueEvent(() -> postTouchEvent(finger, false, 0, 0));
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The issue is however with the `ACTION_MOVE` event, I'm getting the an `IllegalArgumentException` for accessing my index id's. This is happening only when I tap three or more fingers on the screen at once, but it is still an issue. The exception is as follows.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 61026
Process: com.shc.silenceengine.tests.android, PID: 23077
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
    at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:2014)
    at com.shc.silenceengine.backend.android.AndroidInputDevice.lambda$onTouch$14(AndroidInputDevice.java:228)
    at com.shc.silenceengine.backend.android.AndroidInputDevice.access$lambda$6(AndroidInputDevice.java)
    at com.shc.silenceengine.backend.android.AndroidInputDevice$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error because I'm doing the for loop only up to `e.getPointerCount()` so there is no chance of the index going out of the code.

I don't want to track the pointer ID's, I just want a raw list of pointers and these events make up in my engine list to the next frame.

Anyone point me where the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` from a separate (later) thread - it's likely that  the `MotionEvent` object's internal state has changed between the `onTouch()` callback and execution of the thread.

You should only assume the MotionEvent object is valid during the `onTouch()` method and retrieve the values for `getX()` and `getY()` to pass to the thread *before* the method exits.